# Instantiating Array and Instantiating each Member at once

Tags: c#, arrays, element, instantiation

Consider the following case:

```
ColumnDefinition[] columns = new ColumnDefinition[2];
columns[0] = new ColumnDefinition();
columns[1] = new ColumnDefinition();
```

After instantiating columns as an array of ColumnDefinition, I needed to explicitly instantiate each array element. Of course, it could have been done using loops, but I was wondering if there was something simpler which would instantiate every element at once after instantiating the Array type itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a little LINQ:

```
var columns = Enumerable.Repeat(new ColumnDefinition(), 10).ToArray();
```

Adjust the count passed to [`Repeat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899.aspx) for the size of array. However this will lead to the same object being saved in each element of the array. So maybe the creation needs to be repeated:

```
var columns = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10).Select(i => new ColumnDefinition()).ToArray();
```

Comment: After executing the above, columns will be an array with 10 elements, indexed from 0 to 9?

Comment: That's not the same thing - that creates *one* ColumnDefinition object, and an array with 10 references to it.

Comment: Won't that make each element a reference to the same `ColumnDefinition`?

Comment: @Gunner: Yes, it is a zero based array with 10 elements.

Comment: @Richard: Downvote removed (had to perform a whitespace-only edit to do so :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var columns = new []{new ColumnDefinition(), new ColumnDefinition()};
```

Works as expected.

Comment: But that's two new ColumnDefinition(), how about a single one?

Comment: Than Richards answer should would be what you'r looking for.

Comment: @Gunner: It's what your question asked for. If you'd wanted several references to a single instance, you should have asked for that.

Comment: @Jon: Perhaps the question needs a little rewording, basically what I want is, each array element should be instantiated using the default(or any other, but all same) constructor, without explicitly iterating over each array element by writing additional codes.

Comment: @Gunner: Well *something* needs to iterate... you now have several options, of course.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, any solution using anything other than a simple `for` loop for this will have a horrible performance and a `for` loop would only take 3 lines anyway.

```
var columns = new ColumnDefinition[2];
for (int i = 0; i <= columns.Count(); i++) {
    columns[i] = new ColumnDefinition();
}

// This is also a shorthand which compiles to above but only valid for types with
// default contructor as above (i.e. string[] array cannot be initialized with this)
columns.Initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.Initialize Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.initialize.aspx)
Initializes every element of the value-type Array by calling the default constructor of the value type.

Comment: That looks more like it, but one problem is it says on the MSDN page that, this will work with only Value type.